# Pass variable to observer from controller does not works

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

How can i pass variable to observer from controller?
Or is there a way to wait that execute observer before execute method in controller?

Answer (score 2):

**try this code**

> Config.xml

```
<global>
  <events>
    <my_custom_event>
      <observers>
        <namespace_modulename_my_custom_event_observer>
          <type>singleton</type>
          <class>modulename/observer</class>
          <method>my_custom_method</method>
        </namespace_modulename_my_custom_event_observer>
      </observers>
    </my_custom_event>
  </events>
</global>
```

> Use this code in controller file

```
<?php
..
$event_data_array  =  array('cid' => '123');
Mage::dispatchEvent('my_custom_event', $event_data_array);
..
?>
```

> use this code in observer file

```
<?php
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer
{
  public function my_custom_method($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();

    // getter method to fetch varien object passed from the dispatcher
    $varien_object = $event->getVarienObj();
    $varien_object->setCid('456');
  }
}
?>
```

**OR**

**You can also refer below links to get the idea how them works**

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-events-in-magento-with-the-observer-pattern--cms-22120

http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-magento-events-customer-first-order/

http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/mini-tutorial-dispatching-your-own-event-in-magento/

Comment: why $varien_object->setCid('456') ? where is the variable passed?

Comment: if you want update variable(cid) value then you can update in observer file.

Comment: but i want to get value from controller not update it. i try with this code $cid = $varien_object->getCid(); but get error

Comment: can you add your error here?

Comment: Call to a member function getCid() on a non-object

Comment: echo $varien_object->getCid(); try this to get value

Comment: same error again